# Call <link rel="stylesheet" href=""> On A Specific Part Of My Page Without Overriding My Current CSS Style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, php, jquerymobile

I am trying to call `<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">` in the header.php that is linked to my post_form page for the jQuery file uploader that is on the post_form without it overriding the css for the rest of the page. I have tried switching the order of the list of css styles, attempted to call it inline using  around the `<th>Image:</th>
                        <td width="250">
                            <!-- The fileinput-button span is used to style the file input field as button -->
    <span class="btn btn-success fileinput-button">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
        <span>Select files...</span>
        <!-- The file input field used as target for the file upload widget -->
        <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <!-- The global progress bar -->
    <div id="progress" class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- The container for the uploaded files -->
    <div id="files" class="files"></div>
    <br>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="bubble-left"></div>
                            <div class="bubble-inner">600x400px</div>
                            <div class="bubble-right"></div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>` for the file uploader to no avail.
[image: this is the css override from the bootstrap.min.css]
[image: this is the post_form where the default css style shows, but the css style for the jquery file uploader doesnt]

Comment: Welcome to SF.SE user29395. While this would normally seem to be off-topic here in this particular forum as it seems on the surface to be a CSS question, the answer it's elicited appears to be one that's universally helpful to all users in our forum. Thank you for asking it.

Answer (score 2):

I really doubt that this question belongs here.

The CSS conflicts can be resolved by adding a namespace to your css file. You may use this namespaced bootstrap from [SalesforceFoundation](http://developer.salesforce.org/bootstrap-sf1/index.html).

The above css file uses `bootstrap` as namespace.

So, if you want your html markup to use style from this namespaced bootstrap file, you can encapsulate them in the div with bootstrap as class

```
<div class="bootstrap">
//MARKUP USING BOOTSTRAP STYLES.
</div>
```

The rest of the page will not be affected by the bootstrap styles.

You can creates you own namespace using SASS compiler and compiling your own bootstrap.

I also saw a name-spacing too/site in dream-force video, I will post the link if I recall the site name.